# How to select radio button using Robot Framework?

Tags: select, drop-down-menu, radio-button, click, robotframework

```html
<input aria-invalid="false" autocomplete="off" id="BaseId" type="text" class="MuiInputBase-input MuiInput-input MuiAutocomplete-input MuiAutocomplete-inputFocused MuiInputBase-inputAdornedEnd MuiInputBase-inputMarginDense MuiInput-inputMarginDense" aria-autocomplete="list" autocapitalize="none" spellcheck="false" value="AAAAA">
```

```
Click Element       css=#BaseTypeId     EMP:Empty Pallet
Click Element       XPath=(//selete\[@id="BaseId"\])/option\[text() ="AAAAA"\]
Click Element       XPath=(//selete[@id="BaseId" and @class="MuiIconButton-label"])/option[text() ="AAAAA"]
```

Comment: Just in case, could you, please, check if your HTML sample is a real radio button? I mean there is attribute `type="text"` that probably shows that it is not a radiobutton?